# Apply transform animation from view to another view

Tags: android, animation, android-view, transformation

I want to transform two views by using an animation. For example, I have a TextView with a text and an ImageView with an image. I want to be able to make a transformation effect between the TextView and the ImageView. Does somebody know how can be done? There are some library for Android? Thanks in advance!

**I mean something like this:**

[image: Transformations]

Comment: Are you talking about morphing ?

Comment: Yes, I think that yes. Any ideas? See edit please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't morph between two `Views` in Android. You can however give the illusion of this happening by morphing the bitmap of these views.

The one that you have shown in the question is not morphing from one view to another. It's custom drawing done in the same view. If you think about it, it's just manipulations of lines within the `onDraw()` of the `View`. This is how you would do in normal case. So if you want to do this sort of animation in your app, you need to write your own custom `View` and do your own drawing.

But if you were to do this in the Navigation Bar, just like you have shown in the Question, you need to write your own custom `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. You can refer the code here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.java

In this you can refer to the static class `DrawerArrowDrawableToggle`. But most of the work is done in its parent class `DrawerArrowDrawable`. This is the one responsible for the `Hamburger to Arrow` animation that's provided by default in Android. So you will need to write your own `Drawable`.

```
 /**
  * A drawable that can draw a "Drawer hamburger" menu or an arrow and animate between them.
  * <p>
  * The progress between the two states is controlled via {@link #setProgress(float)}.
  * </p>
  */
 public class DrawerArrowDrawable extends Drawable{}
```

Comment: OK. Thank you very much. I'll find the way to do it using that method.